# Why doesn't ECS task scale up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, cpu-usage, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I created a service in AWS ECS and configured the maximum number of tasks to 30. And the desired task number is 2. I also configured CPUUtilization >= 75 as scale-up and CPUUtilization < 25 as scale-down.

I use `Artillery` to send 200 requests per second to my service on ECS and I can see the CPU usage reached 100%. This test lasts 2 minutes so 24000 requests in the total.

But the number of tasks under the service is always 2. It seems that the service never scale-up based on CPU usage. I wonder what else I have missed in the configuration.

Comment: Check if you have "stopped" tasks. May be it tried to scale up but due to some other constraints like resource allocation or else, it fails to start and settle down under 'stopped' tasks.

Comment: For how long the CPU is 100 %? It should be for the period until it triggers the alarm.

Comment: It takes less than 2 minutes to reach 100% cpu

Comment: @LeoPrince I have checked that there is no stoped tasks

Answer (score 0):

Check your alarms in CloudWatch > Alarms, you can see there if your alarms are actually firing. You will also see a threshold description like "CPUUtilization < 10 for 10 datapoints within 10 minutes".

My guess would be that your threshold is misconfigured. I.e. you check too many datapoints within too long period of time. Start with something like "1 datapoint within 1 minute" and work from there.

It also helps checking "Activity History" in EC2 > Auto Scaling Groups. Together with CloudWatch this normally gives you a pretty good picture of what was scaled (or not) and why.